# MongoEngine: database names cannot contain the character '.'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mlab

I am trying to insert document using mongoengine in my python script but it raises this exception

```
(<class 'pymongo.errors.InvalidName'>, InvalidName("database names cannot contain the character '.'",), <traceback object at 0x000000000844F708>)
```

Connection string is mongodb://user:pass@ds042487-a0.mlab.com:42487/db-name

Any suggestions on how to fix this??

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to connect to the question?

Comment: Is there a `.` in your database name?

Comment: from mongoengine import *

try:
  connect(mongodb://user:pass@ds042487-a0.mlab.com:42487/db-name)
except Exception as e:
  print e

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than using

`connect("mongodb://user:pass@server_url:port/db-name")`

use this

`connect( db='db-name', username='user', password='pass', host='mongodb://user:pass@server_url:port/db-name')`

It worked for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your database name shouldn't [contain any of these characters:](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/v3.3/pymongo/database.py#L38)
`' ', '.', '$', '/', '\\', '\x00', '"'`

Check your database name. The Mongo driver also enforces this rule so the chance that you have a database with a dot in its name is slim.

Comment: I want to add that I found this applies to **collection** names as well

Answer (score 0):

I use `python driver 3.4v` which is shared cluster format connection string, I try diferent connection string but it doesn't work for me, here's the [Connection Strings URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples-1) for mongoengine

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. In the .env file:

```
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://papi:****@cluster0.zvhnr7t.mongodb.net/social media app?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I fixed it by removing the space between social media app like this:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://papi:*****@cluster0.zvhnr7t.mongodb.net/socialmediaapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

so remove the space and check also there is no space between the username and password.